# How to fix ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'run.services.setIamPolicy' denied on resource '

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

New to working with GCP and I am running into an issue when trying to deploy a function with the `--allow-unauthenticated` flag.

It keeps returning the error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'run.services.setIamPolicy' denied on resource '...
```

I am an owner on the project and have admin iAm role for both Cloud Functions and Cloud Run, but it still returns this error.

I did find this response here: [Permission Denied Error while deploying Gen2 Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73315795/permission-denied-error-while-deploying-gen2-cloud-function#answer-73316383)

But was unable to find the setting/role I needed to give myself in order to get this to work.

How can I fix it so this warning doesn't show and I can deploy a function and use the `--allow-unauthenticated` flag?

Comment: On the host that you're running the command, confirm that `gcloud config get account` matches your expected (Project Owner) account. The Project Owner role should include `roles/run.admin` and so it should work.

Comment: You have one identity with the Owner role, however, the CLI must be using another identity such as a service account. Double-check how you have authorized the CLI.

Comment: @DazWilkin  Running that command the account returned was the expected account.

Answer (score 0):

From the CLI, after verifying the account was correct, I needed to run

```
gcloud auth login
```